# Categories list into registration form

Tags: posts, categories, custom-field, user-registration

I'm trying to create a custom user registration form used for Educational website.

Is it possible to automatically retrieve categories of posts (custom posts) in the registration form.

The form should be:

username  :
password  :
first name:
last name :

optional

(category list) (courses list)

if user choose  it will automatically show related sub-categories example:

(course1)
  - (sub-course-1)
   - (lesson 1)
   - (lesson 2)
  - (sub-course-2)
   - (lesson 1)
   - (lesson 2)

Is there a way to do such thing into registration form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to add extra fields to the wordpress user registration form that I know of is to use the related registration form filters:

1. [register_form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_form) - This is used to add your fields to the registration form
2. [registration_errors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors) - This is used to validate your fields
3. [user_register](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register) - This is used to add your custom user_meta data to the system
4. and maybe [register_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/register_post) - This can be used to do other things pre-validation

Comment: Thank you for your reply and suggestions. Is there any example for Register Post Category like a parameter to be added to the registration form that says if user choose Category 1 load all related sub categories and so on. Thank you again!

Comment: If you want it to be dynamic, you would need to attach some javascript to it. Otherwise, you could use wp_query to grab all categories and build out your custom category list in a tree style and they could just scroll through and choose one.

Comment: thank you for your reply and explanation. Excuse me for asking much. Can you advice me of an example script or code that does the job? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have anything lying around that does this currently. You might check some of the free subscriber plugins available on the core wordpress site and look through them.